# Find $p \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the equation $\sin x + p \cos x = 2p$ has solutions.

Tags: trigonometry

I am given the following equation:

$$\sin x + p \cos x = 2p$$

With $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and I have to find $p \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the above equation has solutions.

How should I approach something like this? I don't see any sum\product formulas or any trigonometric identities that I could use to transform the equation.

Comment: I would rewrite the equation to give $p$ as an expression in terms of $x$.

Comment: Search: harmonic addition theorem. This would show that solutions exist only when $$\bigg\vert\frac{2p}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}\bigg\vert\le 1$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this technique

$$\sin x + p \cos x = 2p \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}\sin x + \frac{p}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}\cos x=\frac{2p}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}$$

If we define $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}=\cos(\theta)$ therfore $\frac{p}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}=\sin(\theta)$, and from there

$$\sin(x+\theta)=\frac{2p}{\sqrt{1+p^2}} \Rightarrow x=\sin^{-1}\left( \frac{2p}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}\right)-\theta+2k\pi,x=\sin^{-1}\left( \frac{2p}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta+2k\pi$$

Therefore in orther that we have a solution, we must have

$$\Biggl| \frac{2p}{\sqrt{1+p^2}} \Biggl|\le1 \Rightarrow \frac{4p^2}{1+p^2}\le1 \Rightarrow |p|\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: I think your very last step is mistaken, and should say $\vert p \vert \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$.

Comment: Awww, come on!!! again i rushed :C. Thanks for head up man, corrected it.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald How is it that if $\cos (\theta) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 + p^2}}$ then $\sin (\theta) = \dfrac{p}{\sqrt{1 + p^2}}$?

Comment: Because $\sin^2(\theta)=1-\cos^2(\theta)$.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald Just a quick question, I am still kind of confused. How did you get the idea to multiply the expression by $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 + p^2}}$? If I would get this exercise in say, an exam, I would never have the idea to multiply by something that looks that obscure. The same goes for those definitions of $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: You know, most of math are the stuff that you learn through study and solving various exercises and problems, if some of them are new to you, don't worry. Try hard to understand concepts very well but when it comes to applying those concepts, it's a matter of skill that comes through practice. They are techniques, like the techniques you will learn for various kinds of integration. As one of the big daddies of math says :"Young man, in mathematics you don't understand things. You just get used to them."  xD xD, the great John von Neumann, may his wise soul rest in peace .

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $\sin x=\pm \sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$ into $\sin x + p \cos x = 2p$ and rewrite the equation in the quadratic form in terms of $t = \cos x$,

$$(p^2+1)t^2-4p^2t+4p^2-1=0$$

To have solutions, its discriminate satisfies

$$\Delta = b^2-4ac = -12p^2+4 \ge 0$$

which yields $p\in [-\frac1{\sqrt3},-\frac1{\sqrt3}]$.

Comment: Since the roots are values of cosine function, the roots must lie between $[-1,1]$. We need to apply those conditions as well right?

Comment: @PythonSage - That's a good point. Looks like it satisfies automatically. Will verify.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The extrema are in points where $\cos x-p\sin x=0$. From continuity, the absolute value in extremum should be $\geq |2p|$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution

$$\sin x=\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2},\cos x=\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$ where $t=\tan\dfrac x2$ to form a quadratic equation in $t$

To admit solutions,  the only condition is $:t$ has to be real

i.e, the discriminant of the quadratic equation must be $\ge0$